# Correct Way for Density Independence in UI?

Tags: android, user-interface

Finally i think i understood how i should achieve that my UI elements occupy same physical size independent of screen density.

In my layout, i have one button:

- Button: 150x100 dp.

Now if i load this layout in a HDPI device the button gets scaled and therefore it doesn't occupy same physical size as in the MDPI device.

So i placed a new layout with the same name in the layout-hdpi folder with this size:

- Button: 100x67 dp.

Now it looks similiar (not exactly as in MDPI) but close. Is this the correct way?

Comment: `it doesn't occupy same physical size`. But it should. You are either doing or measuring something wrong. 150dpi on an MDPI device should be about 2.4 cm. (more or less)

Comment: Button properties:                                                              android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"                                                                 Still in HDPI the button is BIGGER than in MDPI not the same size. I'm using a relative layout.

Comment: what are the devices exactly, and how much bigger is it? (if you can measure it in physical units?)

Comment: Nexus one HDPI (480x800) and WVGA 5"1 (480x800) MDPI

Comment: densities are classes, which means that there is a margin. In your case the button on the nexus one should be .96 in, and on the other unspecified device .82. Because the nexus in close to the definition of the class, but the other device is much farther (183 dpi instead of 160).

Comment: Okey so there is a margin, but how u calculated that if in the MDPI is 82 in the HDPI should be 96?

Comment: mdpi is the class around 160 ppi. It means that 160 pixels are used to represent a one-inch object for any density associated with this class. the density of the device is 183 dpi (http://dpi.lv/), which means that the relative size of things is 160/183 (0.87, slightly smaller). multiply all this together, it gives you that 150dpi on a MDPI 183ppi device is 0.82 inches. A perfectly 160ppi device would give 0.94, as would a 240ppi HDPI device. (same reasoning goes for the nexus, which is 233 making things a little bigger).